# Exportar a excel solo algunos elementos con django

Tags: python, django, tablas

Estoy intentando exportar uno o muchos registros de un panel a una plantilla de Excel. Si bien yo ya pude exportar toda la tabla a un archivo Excel lo que quiero es poder seleccionar algunas filas y que me exporta solo esa selección y nose como hacerlo.

El view que hice para exportar a excel es el siguiente

````
    ingenials= Ingenial.objects.values_list('ingenial_number', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'street', 'number_dir', 'location', 'cp', 'state', 'dni', 'cuit', 'email', 'phone', 'birth_date', 'admission_date', 'CBU')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/ms-excel")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ingenials.xls"'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws=wb.add_sheet('Ingenials')
    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    columns = ['Legajo', 'Apellido', 'Nombre', 'Calle', 'Numero', 'Barrio / Localidad', 'Codigo Postal', 'Provincia', 'DNI', 'CUIT', 'Mail', 'Celular', 'Fecha de nacimiento', 'Fecha ingreso', 'CBU']

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

    for ingenial in ingenials:
        row_num+=1
        for col_num in range(len(ingenial)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, str(ingenial[col_num]), font_style)
    wb.save(response)

    return response ```

El template es el siguiente:

``` <div class="float-right">
        <a href="{% url 'exc_ingenials' %}" class="btn btn-primary active my-2 my-sm-0">Exportar a excel</a>
    </div>
    {% if ingenials  %}
    <table class="table table-sm table-striped mt-3 display mt-3" id="IngenialsTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="th-sm">Nombre</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Apellido</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Calle</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Numero</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Barrio / Localidad</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Codigo postal</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Provincia</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Mail</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Teléfono</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Nacimiento</th>
          <th class="th-sm">Ingreso</th>
          <th class="th-sm">DNI</th>
          <th class="th-sm">CUIT</th>
          <th class="ht-sm">CBU</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> ```
````

Comment: Concretamente donde esta la duda o error?. Hasta donde veo ese código pareciera generar de manera exitosa el archivo de Excel con todos los registros. Lo único que quieres agregar es que ahora ya no sean todos los registros, si no solo aquellos que cumplan una condición?, en dado caso solo agrega en la primera línea un filter con la condición `ingenials=Ingenial.objects.filter(................).values_list('ingenial_number', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'street', 'number_dir', 'location', 'cp', 'state', 'dni', 'cuit', 'email', 'phone', 'birth_date', 'admission_date', 'CBU')`

Comment: Exactamente eso, el archivo lo creo perfecto sin problemas pero no quiero que sean todos sino que algunos ósea hacer yo la selección. Voy a probar agregando un checkbox a los témplate y asi hacer el filter

Comment: Si tus filtros son muy avanzados (o muchos) te recomiendo que le des un vistazo a `django-filter`. Ese paquete te va ayudar a definir los filtros de manera sencilla, procesar tus peticiones conforme a esos filtros y retornar un queryset ya filtrado que solo lo reemplazarías por tu queryset `Ingenial.objects`